# How to find the index of an event target's parent node in JS?

Tags: javascript, dom

When the page loads, an array is made that holds a group of divs and is used as a global variable catGroup. Each div has a button as a child, and when clicked, the target is saved as a global variable targ. What I'm trying to do is determine the index of the button's parent node every time it is clicked. I haven't been able to find a way to make this happen. Any help is appreciated.

```
i = catGroup.findIndex(node => node == targ.parentNode);
```

Comment: How do the divs get into catGroup?  If you are using `document.getElementsByTagName("div")` = that's not an array.  But that's good because it will be "live".  THEN you could iterate over items in the HTMLCollection and compare them to the button's parentNode (using for loop with index - what you want!).

Comment: What does the HTML structure look like, exactly?

Comment: If your buttons are actually direct children of your divs, then what you have should probably work. Demo ~ https://jsfiddle.net/aL46nj0y/

Comment: The question I have is… what is (knowing) this index good for?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap an element around all `<div>`s then register it to the click event:

```
document.querySelector('main').onclick = clickHandler;
```

Get the `<div>` of the button clicked by user:

```
const clicked = e.target;
const act = clicked.parentElement;
```

Collect all `<div>` that are direct descendants of `<main>`:

```
const divs = [...this.querySelectorAll('main > div')];
```

Remove '.active' from all `<div>` and then add `.active` to the parent `<div>` of clicked button:

```
divs.forEach(d => d.classList.remove('active'));
act.classList.add('active');
```

Filter the array of `divs` and return it's index:

<s>idx = divs.flatMap((d, i) => d.className === 'active' ? i : []);</s>

```
idx = divs.findIndex(d => d === act);
// As Peter Seliger suggested -- I brain farted
```

```js
const main = document.querySelector('main');

main.onclick = getIndex;

function getIndex(e) {
  let idx;
  const clicked = e.target;
  const divs = [...this.querySelectorAll('main > div')];

  if (clicked.matches('[type="button"]') || clicked.matches('button')) {
    const act = clicked.parentElement;
    divs.forEach(d => d.classList.remove('active'));
    act.classList.add('active');
    idx = divs.findIndex(d => d === act);
  }
  document.querySelector('section').textContent = idx;
}
```

```css
html {
  font: 2ch/1 Consolas;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh
}

main {
  padding: 5px 20px 10px;
}

section {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 5rem;
}

div {
  width: 8.5ch;
  text-align: center;
}

[type='button'], button {
  display: block;
  width: 10ch;
  height: 3ch;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section></section>
  <div><input type='button' value='0'></div>
  <div><input type='button' value='1'></div>
  <div><input type='button' value='2'></div>
  <div><button>3</button></div>
  <div><input type='button' value='4'></div>
  <div><button>5</button></div>
  <div><input type='button' value='6'></div>
  <div><input type='button' value='7'></div>
  <div><button>8</button></div>
  <div><input type='button' value='9'></div>
</main>
```

Comment: So much example code, and then the main part, finding the parent div's index, is done so wrong in many ways. Firstly the result is not an index, It's an array with exactly one number value item. Secondly the approach, a full array iteration cycle via `flatMap` and then comparing a div's active state? How about directly using what one has, the currently involved `act` element and exiting the index search early via `idx = divs.findIndex(d => d === act);`?

Comment: I agree with the last paet and updated and gave you credit. The rest of your complaints is opinion. I compensated for what wasn't covered in the OP. Also removed blank divs -- reread OP about each div having a button. I originally included the empty divs just in case there were any in the real code. Other than that I suggest you post an answer yourself since mine *"... is done so wrong in many ways"*

Comment: Oh, read my comment again. I think the effort was a nice gesture and all the example code perfectly presents the OP's use case. But ... _"then the main part, finding the parent div's index, is done so wrong in many ways"._ I hope It is 
 understood that I criticized exactly one line of code (finding the index, the OP's very question) which was flawed (_"brain farted"_ as you say yourself) in many aspects. And how the updated solution presents itself right now, nothing prevents it from not getting upvoted.

Comment: It wasn't flawed, it was inefficient, your suggsetion was much more efficient. If the original line was flawed, it shouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in a mouseover event. That's how I did it in my case:

`onMouseOver={(e) => { const idx = Array.from(e.target.parentNode.children).indexOf(e.target); }}`